# PHP send email message coding in utf-8

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a problem with sending mail from php code. I want to use polish characters in email message. I searched many post on stack with the same problem but nothing works.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $to = "...@gmail.com";
 $from = $_POST['email'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $subject = "Wiadomość ze strony";
 $message = "Imię i Nazwisko: " . $name . "\nTelefon kontaktowy: " . $phone . "\n\nTreść wiadomości:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['msg'];

 $headers = "From: $from \r\n". 
            "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
            "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 header('Location: index.html');
}
?>
```

I have asked my friend to check on his vps and this code work correctly. So there must be a problem with server. I use linuxpl.com.

I found the solution. Polish characters work fine when I added this line in html form.

```
accept-charset="ISO-8859-1"
```

Comment: And what's the error you're getting?

Comment: There are no error. Polish characters doesn't work correctly e.g 
Tre¶ć wiadomo¶ci: Ä…Ĺ›Ä‡

Comment: Check if your php file is in utf-8 encoding, also check the "Content-type:"  header of incoming message at gmail.

Comment: Message subject should be mime-encoded in any way.

Comment: Yes, I saved in utf-8 encoding.

Gmail header:
    X-PHP-Originating-Script: 2211:send_email.php
    From: ...@gmail.com
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Message-Id: <E1cuhWX-000718-Rs@s41.linuxpl.com>
    Date: Sun, 02 Apr 2017 17:34:37 +0200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mail($to,utf8_decode($subject),utf8_decode($message),utf8_decode($headers));
```

Comment: After using this I have sth like this:
Tre?? wiadomo?ci:

Comment: This answer has a lot of room for improvement. Could you explain why you think this would help? Why does UTF decoding things change anything? On an unrelated note, this is the appropriate way to answer questions, I've voted to reject your proposed edit to the question. Adding a solution into the question confuses other people that might look at this question.

Comment: In my case i Use html_entity_decode();